# How do I show mathematically that net intrinsic magnetic moment of a substance is $0$?

Tags: condensed-matter, magnetic-fields, solid-state-physics, material-science, magnetic-moment

The following argument is made, keeping in mind the classical theory of diamagnetism. I'm not including the correct quantum mechanical theory in this question.

Consider a material in the absence of some external magnetic field. Let us look at a particular atom, with an unpaired electron revolving around it. This can be thought of as a magnetic dipole, and the dipole moment is given by :

$$\vec{\mu} = -\frac{1}{2}ev\rho \hat{z}$$

Here $\rho$ is the radius of orbit and $\hat{z}$ is the unit vector along an arbitrary direction, that I have fixed to be the $z$ axis.

This is the contribution due to a single electron. Now the argument is made that, since there are a huge number of electrons, their magnetic moments effectively cancel out since they are pointed in random directions. This is why the net magnetization is $0$.

What I want, is a more mathematical version of the above statement.

For example, when we deal with diamagnetic susceptibility, we see that $\chi\sim\rho^2$ for a single atom.To find the net contribution, we first realize that the value of $\rho^2$ might be different for each atom, and so we use the more general $\langle \rho^2\rangle$. This is the average distance of the electron perpendicular to the axis along the external field.We then realize that all atoms are not oriented along the $z$ axis, and instead of using the distance perpendicular to the $z$ axis, we use the more general $\langle r^2\rangle$ which is the mean squared distance from the nucleus.We see that $\langle r^2\rangle=\frac{3}{2}\langle \rho^2\rangle$.Hence we get, $\chi \sim\frac{2}{3}\langle r^2\rangle.$
This is the average susceptibility per atom. The total volume susceptibility would be just multiplying this with $N$.

My idea was similar, in the sense, I would replace $\rho$ by $\langle\rho\rangle$ in the expression for the intrinsic magnetic moment $\vec{\mu}$. Then perhaps, I can show using integration that $\langle \rho\rangle=0$ over the entire atom. The average distance of an electron perpendicular to the $z$ axis would be $0$.

Is this a valid mathematical argument to show that the net intrinsic magnetic moment of a substance is $0$ in the absence of an external field ? Moreover, in the presence of an external field, it is only the induced magnetic moment that contributes to the net magnetic moment.

Any help would be highly appreciated.